# runinterval not working for Puppet Agents

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I am running puppet agents on windows.

I am trying to change the interval of Puppet Agent check-in with the Server.

on puppet master, i modified `puppet.conf` file and added `runinterval = 5m` under agent section. I then restarted `pe-puppet` service. Then i went to the agent and restarted the `Puppet Agent` service.

This did not work and my agent still does not run at 5 minutes interval.

I checked `puppet.conf` file on Agent and i do not see runinterval being populated there.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `runinterval` on each specific agent. Each puppet master/agent has their own `puppet.conf`. You can write a simple module to push `puppet.conf` changes to the various agents.

*Side note: I always define the time in seconds - 300 = 5 minutes, 600 = 10 minutes - etc.*